# Sequelize findAll is not a function 4

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

keep getting an error when running my "findAll" function on my routes file. I've searched and it might be because of the way I have my basics.js model folder set up.

It was working before when I had my models exported out, but I changed the model to what I have now because I kept getting an error "define is undefined"

db.js

```
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username' , 'password' , {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
})

const db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

// Models
db.ProUsers = require('../model/User.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.ProPersonals = require('../model/profile_personal.js')(sequelize, Sequelize);

// Foreign Key Connections 
db.ProPersonals.belongsTo(db.ProUsers, {foreignKey: 'fk_user_id', targetKey: 'user_id'});
db.ProUsers.hasOne(db.ProPersonals, {foreignKey: 'fk_user_id', targetKey: 'user_id'});

module.exports = db
```

Basic.js //Model

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Profile_Basics = sequelize.define('basics', {
        ID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        resume: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: false
    });

    return Profile_Basics;
}
```

basics.js // Router

```
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router()
const Basic = require("../model/Basic.js")

// get all jobs
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Basic.findAll()
      .then(basics => {
          res.json(basics)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.send('error: ' + err)
      })
})
```

Comment: In basic.js your model name is Profile_Basics but you refer something called Basic?

Comment: I don't know much about sequlize but I got this same error so many times for a one reason that model cannot found in the controller (in your case it's route). console.log Basic and see what it gives.

Comment: const basic = require('../model').tablename;

Comment: Thank you all, I found the error. I had to pass in my database file and call my model from there. const db = require('../database/db.js');
const Basic = db.Basics;

Comment: you can post your answer